# Add invoice, payments, expenses, etc. into Quickbooks via ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have an ASP.NET application that I would like to connect to my Quickbooks Online account to programmatically enter new invoices, make payments against those invoices and even enter new expenses.  It seems that there are all sorts of APIs and processes for this that have undergone many changes over the years so I am confused as to where to start.  I'm not looking to create a app that I'd release to some sort of App Store or anything, this is just for personal use (automation, etc.)  I'm looking for a simple, straight forward, approach.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that there are all sorts of APIs and processes for this that
>   have undergone many changes over the years

That's an understatement. Intuit is the king of confusing and poorly implemented APIs. :-)

> I'm not looking to create a app that I'd release to some sort of App
>   Store or anything

Since this is just for your internal use, your only option at this point is the QuickBooks SDK/qbXML gateway for QuickBooks Online.

(IPP/Intuit Anywhere are the newest APIs, but as the [FAQs](http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0080_FAQ) state, right now Intuit Anywhere is only for SaaS apps that you're re-selling to others.)

The easiest way to get started with qbXML and QuickBooks Online is by HTTP POSTing data directly to the gateway. Some example code looks like this:

```
string requestUrl = null;
requestUrl = "https://apps.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway";


HttpWebRequest WebRequestObject = null;
StreamReader sr = null;
HttpWebResponse WebResponseObject = null;
StreamWriter swr = null;


try
{
    WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    WebRequestObject.Method = "POST";
    WebRequestObject.ContentType = "application/x-qbxml";
    WebRequestObject.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

string post = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<?qbxml version=""6.0""?>
<QBXML>
<SignonMsgsRq>
<SignonDesktopRq>
<ClientDateTime>%%CLIENT_DATE_TIME%%</ClientDateTime>
<ApplicationLogin>APPLICATION_LOGIN</ApplicationLogin>
<ConnectionTicket>CONNECTION_TICKET</ConnectionTicket>
<Language>English</Language>
<AppID>APP_ID</AppID>
<AppVer>1</AppVer>
</SignonDesktopRq>
</SignonMsgsRq>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError=""continueOnError"">
<CustomerQueryRq requestID=""2"" />
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>"; 

post = post.Replace("%%CLIENT_DATE_TIME%%", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(post);
    post = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
    WebRequestObject.ContentLength = post.Length;
    swr = new StreamWriter(WebRequestObject.GetRequestStream());
    swr.Write(post);
    swr.Close();
    WebResponseObject = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequestObject.GetResponse();
    sr = new StreamReader(WebResponseObject.GetResponseStream());
    string Results = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
finally
    {
        try
        {
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }


    try
    {
        WebResponseObject.Close();
        WebRequestObject.Abort();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

Notice that to use that sample code, you'll need a application login and connection ticket. You can get those by following the DESKTOP REGISTRATION walk-through on our [QuickBooks integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition#connecting_with_the_desktop_model_of_communication).

If you need more abstraction than that, you can also use the QBFC libraries included with the SDK. Be aware that the "QBOEConnector" .NET components have been problematic for people in the past (they require some weird registry edits and stuff for some strange reason...).

You can use the [QuickBooks OSR](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html) (check the "OE" checkbox, uncheck the "US" checkbox, use the "Select Message" drop-down at the top of the screen, and choose the "XML Ops" tab) to view available requests to send to QuickBooks Online. If you don't see it in the list, it's not supported by the QuickBooks Online API.